# Word Match with column name Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am writing a code that takes multiple values from a listbox and searches column names for that same value and adds an `"X"` in that row.

```
lastrow = Workbooks("Master Log").Sheets(AddSamples.Project.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

For i = 0 To (Tests.ListBox12.ListCount - 1)

    M = Tests.ListBox12.List(i)
    For colnum = 3 To colnum = 16

        If Workbooks("Master Log").Worksheets("SMI").Cells(1, colnum).Value = M Then
            Workbooks("Master Log").Worksheets("SMI").Cells(lastrow, colnum) = "X"
            Exit For
        End If

    Next colnum

Next i
```

So for example if M was to have a value of `"Blah"`. I want it to search for `"Blah"` from columns 3 to 16, rows 1 and input a value of `"X"` under that name. It is not working for me. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: _"It is not working for me"_. Please elaborate. Do you get an error?

Comment: no errors. The code runs but does not add the "X" under the column that matches the M variable.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of errors are you getting? Which line does execution choke on? Are you looking for something like this (below)? I've adjusted the syntax on your "For" loop. You had an extra "colnum = " after the "To" that isn't necessary. Also, I didn't see a reason for the "Exit For" statement. It causes the loop to exit as soon as it finds one match. Don't you want to find all matches in columns 3 through 16?

```
lastrow = Workbooks("Master Log").Sheets(AddSamples.Project.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

For i = 0 To (Tests.ListBox12.ListCount - 1)
     M = Tests.ListBox12.List(i)      
     For colnum = 3 To 16    
          If Workbooks("Master Log").Worksheets("SMI").Cells(1, colnum).Value = M Then                 
               Workbooks("Master Log").Worksheets("SMI").Cells(lastrow, colnum) = "X"
          End If
     Next colnum
Next i
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors it's just not adding the "X" under the column that matches. I tried taking the code above and still no good. What I have is two workbooks. One of the workbooks called "Log Sheet" stores some data, the other one called "Master Log" store the data with the "X". I tried using the match function but it still did not put the X under the matched columns. If it would help, I can upload both the workbooks, and you can take a look at it! Thanks!